# name correl is not defined after the stationary check

Tags: python, correlation, threshold, drop

after the stationary check, i have removed the not stationary, thus, after i want to check the correlation between but i have the errore belove.
name correl is not defined.

```
def get_pair_above_threshold(X,threshold):
    correl=X.corr()
    correl=correl.abs().unstack()
    pairs_to_drop=set()
    cols=X.corr().columns
    for i in range(0, X.corr().shape[1]):
        for j in range (0,i+1):
            pairs_to_drop.add((cols[i],cols[j]))
            
correl=correl.drop(labels=pairs_to_drop).sort_values(ascending=False)
    
return correl[correl>threshold].index

print(get_pair_above_threshold(X,0.7))
```

Comment: It looks like the `return` statement and the line above it need to be indented one more level in order to be inside the function.

Comment: thank you, i have try but i have this error

Comment: 2     """Functiont to return the pairs with correalation above threshold."""
----> 3     correl=X.corr()
      4     correl=correl.abs().unstack()
      5     pairs_to_drop=set()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'corr'